How do I find if a token that just listed on Raydium is a Pump.fun token
am interested in finding pump fun tokens that just listed on Raydium. I want the data to flow continously so am probably thinking a websocket would be ideal. Any ideas how I can go about implementing this solution?

easiest solution would be checking mint address ending with PUMP. But anyone can create a mint address ending with PUMP.

I think OP wants to know which Pump.fun tokens have ALSO only JUST NOW listed on Raydium. Likely to try and snipe them or something like that.

Here's a script that does that. It subscribes over websocket with the blockSubscribe method mentioning the account that's pushing the tokens that completed their bonding curve and migrate to Raydium.
It also prints the token address & the new token's LP address on Raydium. You can also FAFO with the script and extract other details that you need.
Here it is Listening to pump.fun migrations to Raydium.
